# Classify based on which column has greater value in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as shown below:

```
id|value_1 |value_2 |value_3 |value_4
1 |0.2     |0.3     |0.1     | 0.4
2 |0.6     |0.1     |0.1     | 0.2
3 |0.1     |0.2     |0.3     | 0.4
```

I want to classify each row based on the highest value from the columns (value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4).

Expected Output:

```
ID|Category
 1|4
 2|1
 3|4
```

Can someone please suggest a way to achieve this using the SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` for this:

```
select t.*, v.category
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) v.*
      from (values (value_1, 'value_1'),
                   (value_2, 'value_2'),
                   (value_3, 'value_3'),
                   (value_4, 'value_4')
           ) v(val, category)
      order by val desc
     ) v;
```